# how display mysql query count(*) result in textview android using php page

Tags: php, android, json

I'm using a query to output a total record in table using count(*) in mysql database.I want to display count(*) result Retriving Data to textview in application using php page..

Answer (score 0):

For fetching data from MySQL database, you have to create a Web API which helps you to fetch data and display in Android. You have to implement JSON Parsing logic before displaying actual data into TextView.

Comment: i already using JSON Parsing logic for get result and display in view it's working in select * from table name but when using count(*) its not working.result display in php page but not get result in texview

Comment: @user1722880 you should post the PHP code and also the code which you are trying to for displaying data in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, `select count(*) as total from tablename`

1. you can retruve the total value from php and returned as json format.
2. In android, you can parse the json resposne from web API, and set in android textview.

Example: Android code

```
JSONObject jObject;
jObject = new JSONObject(data);
String total = jObject.getString("total");
myView.setText(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  Tasks ", null);
int x = 0;
if (cur.moveToFirst())
{
    x = cur.getInt(0);
}
cur.close();
return x;
```